# Flink Metrics Web UI don't show double value

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, metrics

How can I see double value in flink web ui on dashboard? Maybe, it's possible with something configuration?

When I tried see metrics, like `Meter`, on dashboard view only the integer part of number. In log I can see double value:

[image with dasboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwVmQ.png)

[image with log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL4Gz.png)

Function with metrics: https://github.com/dedkot01/busting-grain/blob/master/grain-generator/src/main/scala/org/dedkot/CounterProcessFunction.scala

File with Flink config: https://github.com/dedkot01/busting-grain/blob/master/local.conf

Full Cloudflow Sbt Project: https://github.com/dedkot01/busting-grain

If u want run project, just use command in project directory `sbt pipeline/runLocal`

If it's not possible in Flink Web UI, where it's possible? (maybe in Grafana?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not found answer how this fix in Flink Web UI.

It's good works in Prometheus and Grafana.

Screenshot from Grafana, value 0.2 is displayed correctly.

[image: Screenshot from Grafana, value 0.2 is displayed correctly]